# Create Closing Flag for Question that has Open Bounty

Tags: support, flags, vote-to-close, bounty

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60200891/why-is-a-d-with-an-arrow-above-the-symbol-to-denote-a-vector) is off topic for Stack Overflow. It does not have anything to do with programming and would be better suited for [Maths Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com).

I was wondering

1. Am I correct in my assumption that this question should be closed on the premise of not being a programming question with regards to the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
2. Is this a potential way to have off topic questions avoid the close queue. Post them on SO (or another exchange) and give them a bounty? For example if your exchange does not have a lot of volume, posting on another high volume exchange in hopes to get a question (not specifically in this case)
3. Should bountied questions not have the ability to get close flags based on what I have previously stated?

Comment: Questions on entropy are on topic at CrossValidated (stats.SE) and they have a notation tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The right flag for this scenario is "flag for moderator attention".  *Only* moderators can refund bounties like this anyway, so any additional flags on this would just add more noise to the circumstance.

Be sure to be explicit and thorough as to why the bounty should be refunded.

Note that I'm not making any statement on whether or not the question belongs anywhere else; the main thing is that it's off-topic *here* and should be dealt with *here* as opposed to migrating it anywhere else.

Comment: I did not know only moderators can refund bounties like that. Thank you!

Comment: @EdekiOkoh: why would this hinge on refunding the bounty or not? Bounties are an investment to attract attention to questions. If that question is off-topic, it should not have received a bounty in the first place – but, "oops I didn't realize" is not an excuse for *asking* an off-topic question, and neither is it for putting a bounty on one.

Comment: It does not hinge on refunding a bounty. The question is why I cannot raise a flag on bountied questions and Makoto stated why - I can but I need to make it a moderator flag and not a normal off topic flag. since its bountied

Comment: @usr2564301 Questions can't be closed while they have a bounty on them. Whether it should have had one in the first place is irrelevant to the fact that you have to get a moderator to deal with it.